# Convert [object Object] into DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a slideshow in jQuery where I have all images and their description in a hidden element with the ID `contain`

Here I want to get all of the containing elements (`img` `span`) pairs so I can iterate them. But issue is:

```
var slides = $('#contain').children(); //[object Object]
console.log(slides);
//console.log(slides.get(0)); //< this is also not working
```

This is returning `[object Object]`. However I want the element as in DOM elements so I can select details, iterate them etc.

How can I get that?

`Complete code:`

```
function startSlideShow(interval) {
var slides = $('#contain').children();
console.log("0: " + slides);
for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(
        function () {
            var slide = $(slides[i]).children();
            $('#currentImage').attr('src', slide[0].src).fadeIn(interval * 100);
            $('#slideDesc').html(slide[1].innerHTML).fadeIn(interval * 100);
        }, interval * 1000);
    }
}
```

`in the html:`

```
<article id="contain">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/925p6M5.jpg" />
        <span>1Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dbBu5rk.jpg" />
        <span>2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VFxPGEi.gif" />
        <span>3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
    </div>
</article>
```

Problem with this is it is throwing me errors like:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined`

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: Not really sure what it is you're trying to do. Your `slides` variable points to a jQuery object that contains all of the matched elements. If you want to iterate over them, get property or attribute values, etc then jQuery already provides functions to do so.

Comment: @j08691 updated please check

Comment: @AnthonyGrist i have updated my question with full code and the error i am getting please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
var slides = $('#contain').children().get();
console.log(slides); // array of dom elements
console.log(slides[0]); // first dom element
```

Or

```
$('#contain').children().each(function(k, v){
    console.log(v);
});
```

[**EXAMPLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/sAMdU/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use $.each

```
slides.each(function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: this is getting me the element but I am finding it hard to insert it in my current logic inst there a way to enable `slides` variable to be iterate-able?